# What's the meaning of rspec?

Tags: graphics, polygons

In the [RegularPolygon page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularPolygon.html), I notice the reference  `RegularPolygon[{x,y},rspec,n]`.
What's the `rspec`?

Comment: They got too lazy to write "`RegularPolygon[{x, y}, {r, θ}, n]` or `RegularPolygon[{x, y}, r, n]`". OTOH, one could have inferred this from the previous usage entries.

Comment: `rspec` can be either a `radius` or `{radius, angle}`: `Graphics[RegularPolygon[{2, 3}, #, 5]] & /@ {5, {5, Pi/4}}`